# Intent to System's "Downloads" application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, download, native

How can i call an intent, to start the Downloads application, that is native in the Android OS.
I have searched a lot for this , and this is as close as I got:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.sec.android.providers.downloads","com.sec.android.providers.downloads.DownloadActivity");
 i.setComponent(comp);
 i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
 self.startActivity(i);
```

I have also tried:

```
   Intent i = new Intent();
            PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.providers.downloads");
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
```

but it gives me a JavaNullPointerException at: i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent();  
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
i.setData(uri);   
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I get this for your code:

    
           02-25 14:52:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(5013): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download }

Comment: What Android SDK are you using? Try passing a file type to the intent as well: `i.setType("file/*");`

Comment: Target API 4.2 (17), minimum 2.3 (10)

Comment: and i get this, by including the setType line:
02-25 16:36:02.120: E/AndroidRuntime(6435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.Red.medicalpaint (has extras) } in com.Red.Fragments.AppLibraryFragment$1@40c67cf0

Comment: You need to set the mimeType as well,  this will avoid the ActivityNotFoundException